# Why are asynchronous runtimes like Tokio necessary?

Tags: rust

My first experience doing a computer system project was building a server using vanilla Java and then a client on an Android phone. Since then, I've found that there are a lot of frameworks to help manage scalability and remove the need to write boilerplate code.

I'm trying to understand what services like [Tokio](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial) and [Rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/) enable.

I came across this paragraph on the [Tokio tutorial page](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial) and I'm having a hard time understanding it

> When you write your application in an asynchronous manner, you enable it to scale much better by reducing the cost of doing many things at the same time. However, asynchronous Rust code does not run on its own, so you must choose a runtime to execute it.

I first thought a "runtime" might refer to where the binary can run, but it looks like Tokio just provides functions that are already available in the Rust standard library while Rayon implements functions that aren't in the standard library.

Are the standard implementations for asynchronous functions written poorly in the standard library or am I not understanding what service Tokio is providing?

Comment: Hi, I come from javascript and I know a teensy bit of rust. In javascript we have the event loop which decides on what the thread should be doing. I'd imagine that tokio works much the same way in that it provides your program with an event loop without you having to think about building a queue of functions to run yourself

Comment: Rust's standard library tries to be thin enough to not be a "runtime" -- contrast with Go, which has its own ABI; you can't run Go code without the Go runtime, but you can call Rust from C or any other language without a bunch of heavyweight glue for managing things moving in/out of the runtime.

Comment: There's a limit to what kind of async functionality you can provide without a runtime, because you need _something_ to keep track of code that's waiting for something it depends on before it's schedulable to take place, unless you're going to limit async calls to being usable in specific blocks for which code generation is done (where the only jumps possible are between things in those blocks) -- that's the approach that Clojure's core.async takes, f/e.

Comment: If you're familiar with green threads, you can think of a cooperative thread scheduler  as something pretty closely related to a runtime in the relevant sense, insofar as it's a whole bunch of heavyweight infrastructure added in userland (meaning, not provided by the OS kernel) to try to move the flow of control between different pieces of a running program.

Comment: *Are the standard implementations for asynchronous functions written poorly in the standard library* — I don't believe there are *any* asynchronous function in the standard library. What functions have you found that are marked `async`?

Comment: @Shepmaster I was going through the [multithreaded web server](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-00-final-project-a-web-server.html) and made the mistake of believing that async and multithreaded were the same and then came across [promises](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.0/futures/struct.Promise.html). Is promise part of standard just not with async?

Comment: @financial_physician Rust does not have promises, it has [`Future`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/future/trait.Future.html)s. An `async` function produces a type that implements the `Future` trait. Note that you've linked to documentation of an old version of that library (which isn't the standard library anyway). See the [current version](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: What do you mean by `you can't run Go code without the Go runtime`? Go is a fully compiled programming language. When compiled it runs exactly like C meaning you don't need to have a runtime installed for that (like .Net, Java, etc.)

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder, the runtime is compiled into each executable; it's what does things like goroutine scheduling. Go's maintainers describe it as a runtime themselves; read https://pkg.go.dev/runtime

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder, ...for our immediate purposes, the point here is that Go depends on having a layer that's in charge of flow control and coroutine scheduling, in the exact same sense that Tokio provides a runtime to be in charge of flow control in async Rust. They're both compiled to native CPU instructions; bytecode interpreters are a subset of the larger category of runtimes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `the runtime is compiled into each executable`. Thanks for mentioning that. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rust currently does not provide an async runtime in the standard library. For full details, see [Asynchronous Programming in Rust](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/08_ecosystem/00_chapter.html), and particularly the chapter on "The Async Ecosystem."

> Rust currently provides only the bare essentials for writing async code. Importantly, executors, tasks, reactors, combinators, and low-level I/O futures and traits are not yet provided in the standard library. In the meantime, community-provided async ecosystems fill in these gaps.

Rust has very strict backward compatibility requirements, and they haven't chosen to lock-in a specific runtime. There are reasons to pick one over another (features versus size for example), and making it part of the standard library would impose certain choices that aren't clearly the right ones for all projects. This may change in the future as the community projects better explore this space and help determine the best mix of choices without the strong backward compatibility promises.